# is Directory.GetFiles(anyString) equal to Directory.GetFiles(anyString, "*")?

Tags: c#, .net

I am going to make the following change on the legacy code and it is being referenced by a lot of code, so I cannot really test everything manually. is the following two code behave identically?

```
Directory.GetFiles(anyString)

Directory.GetFiles(anyString, "*")
```

any document/reference will be appreciated! thanks

Comment: are you familiar with `MSDN` why not check the documentation online when doing a MSDN Google search for the following `Directory.GetFiles()`

Comment: @MethodMan I checked MSDN but it does not explicitly mentioned they are the same ...

Comment: I am not 100% certain but most of the MSDN documentation gives ample amount of information in regards to that `Method and its Overloads`

Comment: @MethodMan but this is not the case (I am hoping you can cancel the down vote if it was done by you ;p )

Comment: there are many that choose to downvote for whatever reason I can't cancel something that does not pertain to me.. sorry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the source code of `Directory.GetFiles(aDirectory)`

```
public static String[] GetFiles(String path)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String[]>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return InternalGetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}
```

and this is the source code of `Directory.GetFiles(aDirectory, aPattern)`

```
public static String[] GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (searchPattern == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("searchPattern");
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String[]>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return InternalGetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}
```

So, yes they are the same...  [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,f9704790d3b23471)